# Accessing 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' from SQL Job Agent

Tags: sql-server, excel

I need to execute a stored procedure by job agent, that sp connects to 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' and gets data from excel sheet.
when I execute sp, It's work. but when execute it by job agent it doesn't work.
My code is here:
First I wrote a return value procedure to get excel sheet name:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spExcelSheetName]
@TableName nvarchar(250) output

AS

declare @table Table (TABLE_CAT nvarchar(50), TABLE_SCHEM nvarchar(50), TABLE_NAME nvarchar(50), TABLE_TYPE nvarchar(50), REMARKS nvarchar(50))
insert into @table
    EXECUTE SP_TABLES_EX 'ExcelSource';
select @TableName = TABLE_NAME from @table
```

Then a sp for getting data from excel sheet and insert into my sql table:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spConvertExcel]

AS
begin
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.servers WHERE name = N'ExcelSource')
    EXEC master.sys.sp_dropserver 'ExcelSource','droplogins'  

EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 'ExcelSource', '',
   'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
   'D:\Test\Personel.xlsx',
   NULL,
   'Excel 8.0'
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'ExcelSource', 'false'
EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1   

declare @SheetName nvarchar(250)
exec spExcelSheetName @TableName = @SheetName OUTPUT

declare @Query nvarchar(max)
set @Query = 
N'SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
  ''Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES;Database=D:\Test\Personel.xlsx'',
   ['+@SheetName+']);'

delete from ExcelPersonels
insert into ExcelPersonels
    exec sp_executesql @Query;

delete from Personels 
where personelcode in (select personelcode from ExcelPersonels)

update Personels set IsActive = 0

insert into Personels
    select *, 1 from ExcelPersonels

end
```

This sp run without any problem, but when I want to run it by Job agent it doesn't work :(
job code is : exec (spConvertExcel)
Even I tried: osql –E –Q “exec spConvertExcel”
but it didn't work too.

error massage is:
Message
Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLAgent$SQL2014. Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "ExcelSource". [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7303)  OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "ExcelSource" returned message "Unspecified error". [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 7412).  The step failed.

thanks for all replies.

Comment: is this the code your are executing when the job runs? if so change it to `exec spConvertExcel`

Comment: you created the linked server `ExcelSource` but you didn't use that at all. Also i didn't see any declaration of @Query

Comment: Seems like SQL Agent ID permission issue. What is the error message?